# Как попробовать понять, почему происходит ошибка соединения с хостами в PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, ftp, mikrotik

Ситуация такова: все прекрасно работало, `PHPStorm` без проблем загружал и скачивал файлы с удаленных хостов, а также отображал их содержимое на вкладке `Remote Host`. Но в какой-то момент он вдруг перестал это делать и при открытии проекта и попытке просмотра содержимого хостов происходит такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфигурация у меня такая: `PHPStorm` установлен локально в `Win 7`, проекты лежат на `NAS`, подключенному к роутеру, лежат они на `iSCSI`-дисках, подключенных к `Win 7`. Единственное, что необычного происходило за промежуток времени, в который все сломалось, следующее: я настроил `VPN`-сервер на роутере и подключился к нему на удаленном компьютере со все той же `Win 7`, где в последствии подключил все те же `iSCSI`-диски и поработал с парой проектов, размещенных на них. Но я делал это и ранее, и никаких проблем замечено не было.

На описанное не влияет не перезагрузка роутера (`Mikrotik`), ни обновление его прошивки, ни обновление `PHPStorm`, ни попытка открыть проекты/хосты, которые не открывались на машине, на которой я подключался к сети с `NAS` через `vpn`, ни перезагрузка компьютера. Самое обидное, что пока что происходит показанное на картинке, невозможно нажать кнопку `[...]`, где можно попытаться что-либо проверить в настройках хостов, или же попытаться добавить новый хост.

При этом те же хосты из той же `Filezilla` прекрасно открываются, да и вообще интернет работает без проблем. Собственно, и на том компьютере, который открывал проекты удаленно, они все также продолжают открываться, и работа с удаленными хостами там тоже без проблем ведется. Так вот, подскажите, в какую сторону копать и как вообще попробовать отладить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я [получил](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304821/6741620) ответ на свой аналогичный вопрос на англоязычной версии SO, поэтому оставлю его тут и переведу:

Для того, чтобы включить отладку самой IDE, следует воспользоваться [следующей инструкцией](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs). После этого можно зайти в `Help | Show Log in ...`, либо просто открыв директорию с логом, и посмотреть результат своих действий.

В итоге, на основании полученного мною лога, было решено, что проблема с файлом паролей, который указывается в настройках тут: `Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | System Settings | Passwords`. При проверке оказалось, что действительно, если пароль к этому файлу был по какой-либо причине изменен, то IDE будет постоянно пытаться якобы подключиться к хосту, тогда как на самом деле она банально виснет на этапе попытки открытия файла с паролями. По идее, это глюк, который рано или поздно должны будут исправить.

Уточнение: на самом деле, пароль к файлу не менялся, однако у меня этот файл использовался через папку облака сразу на двух компьютерах, и когда такое происходит, даже если не одновременно, пароль на этот файл вроде как меняется, даже если в настройках IDE и там и там был указан на самом деле один и тот же пароль. В общем, не делайте так.